# Setting and MSYS Home and abbrviating the directory in the prompt line

Tags: bash, bashrc, msys

I run Msys specifically for running OMNETpp - a simulation library. I modified the mingw environment setup scripts in order to get it to start with my home directory, `~/`, by setting up `HOME`.

### Example Problem

```bsh
    ~$
    ~$ cd Documents
    /c/Users/<name>/Documents$ cd ~
    /c/Users/<name>
```

When I start the console it greets me with `~$`

As Soon as I change the directory it then replaces `~` with the full path from root. i.e. `/c/Users/<name>` at the prompt. Going back to the home directory it no longer abbreviates.

### What must I change in bashrc to not do this?

I have this as part of the `bash.bashrc` but I do not understand what it does, other than that it is relevant!

```bsh
    PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\[\e[33m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s) ")\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by removing a trailing slash from my `$HOME` variable